# How to encoding multiple json object in php

Tags: php, json

I am working on a project where a user has to fill up a form and can upload multiple documents. Everytime he uploads a document, he calls a webservice which returns a JSON file with id and type.

Since he can upload multiple documents so the webservice is called many times. When he completes his form and submits it, I need to send a json with the multiple id and type that I have received previously from JSON.

This is the JSON that I need to send to the server when the user finally submits the form:

```
"docls":[  
       {  
           "id":"123",
           "ty":"101",
        },
        {  
           "id":"456",
           "ty":"102",
        }
],
```

How do I encode the JSON when I dont know how many files the user has uploaded?

P.S. I have already been able to get the response from the first JSON in the form of 'id' and 'ty'. Do I need to store it in array? If yes then how do I decode it into json?

```
$json_string = array(
'docls' =>  array (     
                        'id' => '123',
                        'ty' => '101',                            
                        ), 
                    );
```

Comment: Just add them to a multidimensional array and encode the array. An unrelated question, what happens if the user is a she? :o

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to build the array with `php` then `json_encode` it when your ready to send it back to the server

```
// Create an array to hold the documents
$documents = [];

// push each document into the array as the user does their thing
$documents[$id] = $ty;

// When the user is finished
$json = json_encode($documents);
```

Comment: Well I don't know how many documents he uploads. If he uploads more than one documents then how do I send it using the same json object '$id' and '$ty'?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just have to use `json_decode` to convert json string you receive to php array, and `json_encode` to convert convert php array to json formatted string.

Check this example:

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```

more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)